# Counting same values between rows in Open Office Calc

Tags: countif, openoffice-calc

(Open Office Calc) I have two rows of the same length, containing letters.

Suppose the two rows are A1:Z1 and A2:Z2.

I want to check if A1=A2, B1=B2, ... Z1=Z2 and output in one cell how many of these conditions are true.

I tried using COUNTIF but the condition can only refer to a fixed cell, not to a "moving" cell. In this case I would like to be able to write something like "COUNTIF(?1= ?2)" where "?" is the column index.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:Z1=A2:Z2)
```